# How often does XNA on WP7 read touches state?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, xna

How often does XNA on WP7 read touches state? Can I  make XNA do it more often?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XNA's Update() method (one of the default five) is called 60 times a second, so the touch state can be updated in there thus meaning it is also updated 60 times a sec. Its your choice how you update the touch state. The win phone os will have internal updates but for your game you can check the states through the [TouchPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff434208.aspx) class.